# Qt 4.5.2 - linux - change library root

Tags: qt, qmake, qtembedded

I have 2 versions of Qt for different arm devices and different toolchains: Qt 4.5.2 and Qt 4.7.3. Both versions are supposed to be placed in /opt/onyx/arm directory :(

The following error is occurred if I move the 1st Qt build in another directory (`/usr/arm-marvell-linux-gnueabi`) and run qmake:

```
#!/bin/sh
export QTDIR=/usr/arm-marvell-linux-gnueabi
/usr/arm-marvell-linux-gnueabi/bin/qmake -o Makefile.qt.onyx.a6x -spec qws/arm-marvell-linux-gnueabi-g++ project.pro

./run_qmake1.sh
Could not find mkspecs for your QMAKESPEC(qws/arm-marvell-linux-gnueabi-g++) after trying:
    /opt/onyx/arm/mkspecs
    Error processing project file: project.pro
```

What could be the issue and how can I resolve the /opt/onyx/arm conflict?

Comment: This is a guess, since I don't have a *nix box to check this on, but something to try is editing all of the .prl files in /usr/arm-marvell-linux-gnueabi/lib and change the QMAKE_PRL_BUILD_DIR to point to /usr/arm-marvell-linux-gnueabi instead of /opt/onyx/arm.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend grepping through /usr/arm-marvell-linux-gnueabi for any references to /opt/onyx. If you can't successfully change them (because they're in a binary), you could use symlinks to switch toolchains as needed.